# PHP проверить дата или нет

Tags: php

каким способом я могу проверить введена дата или нет?

пользователь вводит время как 12:34:45

я сам уже пристыковываю дату и получаю дату '2015-10-21 12:34:45'

и мне нужно либо вернуть Null если время кривое (14:85:12), но и нужно отловить потенциально нормальное время (12:01:5)

Comment: В каком виде поступает?

Comment: пользователь вводит дату и затем эта дата хранится в какой-то переменной?

Comment: конечно. потом проходит валидация и запись в базу

Comment: @des1roer, тогда задать тип этой переменной как `datetime` или `timestamp` и если пользователь ввел некорректное время, выводить сообщение об этом

Comment: не понял можно пример

Comment: @des1roer http://php.net/manual/ru/class.datetime.php

Comment: @des1roer, пользователь вводит значение даты в какое-либо текстовое поле, так? допустим, он ввел какое-то время, затем это время из строки форматировать в формат даты(какие форматы даты в `php` вам лучше знать), и если все ок, то дальше выполнять манипуляции. Если же нет, выводить сообщение об ошибке, что время некорректное.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для приведенного вами формата даты/время можно использовать такую функцию:

```
function is_Date($str){
    return is_numeric(strtotime($str));
}

var_dump(is_Date('2015-10-21 12:44:45'));
var_dump(is_Date('2015-10-21 12:0:0'));
var_dump(is_Date('2015-10-21 32:44:45'));
var_dump(is_Date('2015-10-21 12:64:45'));
```

Выведет

```
bool(true) bool(true) bool(false) bool(false)
```

Comment: действительно работает